# How to download attachment from Exchange using MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, exchange-server

doesnt anyone have experience with downloading CSV attachment using Power Shell?

Previously I used XP_README procedure but it is not supported anymore.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: `xp_readme` doesn't even return any results in Google. In any case, shouldn't you be looking at SSIS? It's a *very* bad idea to use the database and extended procedures to connect to other systems, for obvious security and performance reasons

Comment: +1 for SSIS, have a look at [this task](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download%20Mail&referringTitle=Home) on Codeplex for an example of how it can be done.

Comment: I hhve changed it into Power Shell :) XP_REAME is here: http://193.68.19.127/install/WinXP/spnotes.htm

Comment: There is nothing about xp_reame, xp_readme or anything about exchange or sql server on that link. Windows XP won't even run powershell. In summary that's a very random link. Now: what are you actually trying to do? Just download a CSV attachment from exchange? Is it an on-premise exchange server?

Comment: Don't use SSIS to download CSV attachment from emails. You'll be running a script task inside an SSIS package which is pointless and overcomplicated.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hey Nick,  want to download csv from exchange into folder.

Comment: Here's one link on how to do it: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/writing-simple-scripted-process-to.html You need to write some code and come back with a specific problem

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That is amazing! Thank you!